# Cocos2d - CCMoveBy - finding sprite position

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, position, sprite

I'm using CCMoveBy in an action to shoot a projectile according to the direction of a Sneaky Joystick. I can't seem to get the position of the projectile DURING the action.

I only get the starting positions of the projectile.

CCMoveTo doesn't seem to work either.

Is it possible to get the position of the projectile DURING this action using something similar to CCMoveBy?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

why you are using CCMoveBy or CCMoveTo . Please use ccpAdd and ccpSub in the position of the sprite when joystick moves.Nothing else,and please post some code fot more clearance.

Comment: I'm using a second joystick to shoot in the direction the player points is what I meant. Either way I'll give cppAdd a try.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. What I need to know is there a way to get the position of a sprite while it is moving through CCMoveBy or CCMoveTo. Thanks

Comment: In the update method, it gives me 0,0 for some odd reason. But in the shootBullet method I created, it gives the location of the player where the bullet's starting point is.

Comment: Check your code again i am getting the position change regularly in update method.

Comment: After playing around for awhile and rechecking the update method again, and found that it does in fact show the position of the player! Must have missed that. Guess thats what staying up late does to ya :P thanks for the help!